# Import FTP file from ftp server with FTP over TLS (Explicit)

Tags: import

I would like to be able to import/read a file into Mathematica from an ftp server that requires explicit TSL security with anonymous connection.

```
Import["ftp://gdc.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/pub/products/iers/finals2000A.all"]
```

In other words, I want to connect to server gdc.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov, and download, for example, /pub/products/iers/finals2000A.all.

or under https:

```
Import["https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/products/iers/finals2000A.all"]
```

Help on this is provided here: https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/CDDIS_Archive_Access.html,
but unfortunately there is nothing specific for Mathematica.

I can't get it to work with Mathematica (Import/URLRead/Authentication ...). Could anyone give me an idea on how to do it?

Comment: Why not use `curl` or `wget` to download the file and then `Import`? If you can get either to work then you can call them from WL and `Import`.

Comment: The [link you provided](https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/CDDIS_Archive_Access.html) has instructions for `curl` and `wget` using either `https` or `ftp-ssl`. I don't have an Earthdata account so I cannot test them. `curl` and `wget` are command line tools.

Comment: I was able to download the file without any problems using your `Import["ftp://gdc.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/pub/products/iers/finals2000A.all"] ` verbatim.  The result was a string of `StringLength` 3372719.  Adding the option `"Table"` to the `Import` gave me a list of 17940 sublists.  The first sublist was {73, 1, 2, 41684., "I", 0.120733, 0.009786, 0.136966, 0.015902, "I", 0.808418, 0.000271, 0., 0.1916, "P", -0.766, 0.199, -0.72, 0.3, 0.143, 0.137, 0.8075, -18.637, -3.667},  I did not visit the website itself and do not have any account or credentials that I know of. MMA 12.1.0 for Linux.

Comment: @LouisB Do you have an account to that database, and were you signed in to it? It did not work for me (FetchURL: the connection cannot be opened for ftp; a login page for https).

Comment: @MarcoB I do not have an account for the database.  I was able to get the "FetchURL: ..." error message using MMA 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows 10.  When I tried to access the FTP server via the Windows FTP command, the server gave me "530 Anonymous sessions must use encryption".  I tried curl and wget on my Linux box and both of those got "530 ..." from the server.

Comment: I have seen this allows download that files from the ftp-ssl server using windows 10 pro from cmd command lines, whith "_netrc" file (`machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov login <user> password <password>` site) in %HOME% directory [manual: curl.se/docs/manpage.html]: `curl -c CookiesCurlCommand.txt -n -L -R "cddis.nasa.gov/archive/products/iers/finals2000A.all" -o C:\Transfers\finals2000A.all` or `curl -u anonymous: myEmail@gmail.com --ftp-ssl gdc.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/pub/products/iers/finals2000A.all -o C:\Transfers\finals2000A.all`

Comment: But the idea, for various reasons (speed [it's too slow], among others), is to load the file online directly from Mathematica with Import/URLRead/URLExecute/HTTPRequest, etc functions and user/password ["_netrc" file]- anonymous/email. The problem is how do it.